# Error Event when trying to open applet on a browser

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp

I have done a few Java programs but this is the first one that I'm trying to run as an applet so I might have some basic error.

I compiled all the classes and put them together in a jar file called final.
I followed a few tutorials to make a JNLP file that I called jnlp (yeah, I know, I'm very original:) and on which I called to my jar file and I called the JNLP file from an HTML file.

Those are the last lines of the java console output: (before them, the console is filled with my JNLP file)

```
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
preloader: Added pending event 2: ErrorEvent[url=null label=JNLP not an applet, nor a JavaFX application cause=JNLP not an applet, nor a JavaFX application
```

Here is the JNLP file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="jnlp.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Encryption Software</title>
        <vendor>Atlantis Atlantis</vendor>
        <icon href="encrypt_logo.jpg"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+" href=
           "http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="final.jar"
            main="true" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc
         name="Encryption Software"
         main-class="EncryptApplication"
         width="500"
         height="300">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

Here is the JS used to launch the applet:

```javascript
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {code:'', width:500, height:500};
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'jnlp.jnlp'};
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
```

Comment: You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html). You need `code`, you cannot leave it blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `EncryptionApplication` really an applet?  To be an applet it must extend [`Applet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) or [`JApplet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html).

If it is not an applet, it cannot be embedded in HTML.

If it **is** an applet, the JNLP must declare it as such, so:

```xml
    <application-desc
         name="Encryption Software"
         main-class="EncryptApplication"
         width="500"
         height="300">
     </application-desc>
```

Should be:

```xml
    <applet-desc
         name="Encryption Software"
         main-class="EncryptApplication"
         width="500"
         height="300">
     </applet-desc>
```

### Tips

- Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).
- Avoid applets like you might avoid the plague.  They were always a complete PITA and with recent security updates, have only become more so.  See [Why CS teachers should *stop* teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for my take on the matter.
- It is possible to launch an *application* (e.g. a `JFrame` based app.) from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  They will be subject to the same (very strict) security requirements of applets, but have none of the applet specific problems (see link in previous point for details).
- As mentioned by @ElliottFrisch, it is best to include a valid value for the `code` attribute.  There *are* circumstances in which it can be left out, but I won't get into that right now..

Comment: I have to use an applet and not a java web start because I'm planning to use java methods in my javascript...

Comment: @Amos  My deepest condolences.  What exact Java methods do you need to use?

Comment: I'm trying to make a website which anyone could register and log in to, and send a self encrypted message to some other user, something like Email but I want to do the encryption myself with java so I figured out I could use javascript and PHP to store the users'encrypted messages. It's more of a self-test project than a real useful website so I dn't really mind the security warnings.